# Ansible: Cannot login to local Vagrant server

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have two Vagrant instances running having different IP:

```
192.168.33.17 [Ansible installed here]

192.168.33.19 [Another server where I am trying to connect]
```

My Ansible hosts file is in `/etc/ansible/hosts` and it looks like:

```
[example]
192.168.33.19:2222
```

I can easily connect via SSH to the second server with command:

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.33.19
```

without password.

But running the Ansible command yields error:

```
[root@centos72x64 vagrant]# ansible  example -m ping -u vagrant
192.168.33.19 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

How I can solve this error?

Comment: Can you please suggest how to explain the question? I think this is a minimal explanation and not a story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Ansible hosts file is in /etc/ansible/hosts and it looks like
>
> ```
> [example]
> 192.168.33.19:2222
> ```

You don't put port number in the Ansible inventory file this way. To learn how to do it, confer [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups).

But you also mentioned:

> I can easily connect via ssh to the second server with command
>
> ```
> ssh vagrant@192.168.33.19
> ```

So you don't use port 2222 at all.

Comment: Thank you ! I removed port number and it is working now.